# What query language abides most closely to Codd's relational model of data?

Tags: math, relational-database, relational-algebra

Syntactically, at least, SQL is pretty far off. Thanks!

Comment: Why Codd's? He invented the relational model but it has been further developed since. Take nulls for example. Codd's original model had no concept of nulls. Much later he added the three-value logic with nulls. He later rejected this in favour of two kinds of nulls that  was almost universally rejected. In modern relational theory, all concept of nulls are rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataphor's D4 is said to be pretty close (sole major error being the introduction of a null-like construct that the customers forced upon the developers, IIRC).

The projects listed on The Third Manifesto's project page ( http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Projects.html ) should all be expected to abide even more closely.

Comment: +1 although I think you are mistaken about Dataphor and nulls: read the full story [here](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Reflections-from-implementers.html#Dataphor) ("as we tried to build a practical solution to the problem without introducing nulls into the DBMS, we ran into significant problems...in the end, the simplest practical solution to the problem was the adoption of nulls pretty much as they exist in any given SQL-based DBMS today... This is not to say that we feel that SQL-style nulls are the ultimate solution to this problem, only that we do not feel the issue is settled")

Comment: Dataphor used to be on Darwen's list of "compliant" languages/projects, but was removed as a consequence of "this story".

Comment: It's an interesting read: "we even tried to remedy the situation by defining the null as part of the type system" -- reminds me of something I read recently, [How to Handle Missing Information Using S-by-C](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HTHMIUS-by-C-review-draft.pdf). Perhaps they should go back to the whiteboard :) BTW have you used Dataphor? I tried once but couldn't compile the source and couldn't get any support :(

Comment: Oh good old HTHMIUSBC again :-)  Yes it has turned out to be little more than an exercise in futility.  When Date first saw the draft, his immediate instinct was "but this is special values all over again", and he was right, for the most part.  (He later recognised that one possibly valuable idea was that it showed how we could stay away from forcing the operator implementations to have to accept nulls as a value they have to deal with.)  The only other valuable thing it did was let me come out with a firm conviction that there simply is no elegant solution.  ( :-( )

Comment: Here is what I believe to be an elegant solution to missing information:
https://tenwaystosunday.blogspot.com/2006/07/actively-managing-missing-information.html
and:
https://tenwaystosunday.blogspot.com/2007/04/condition-propagation-renamed-proviso.html

Answer (score 1):

There are the two syntactically very different languages: *Relational Algebra* and *Relational Calculus*, and SQL is a mixture of both. There are plenty of verbatim Relational Algebra implementations, so the matter obviously is not how "faithful" the implementation is.